# Disabled SQL Server Endpoint - now I cannot login

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have SQL Server 2005 on my local machine.  During the studies of SQL Server network configuration, I logged into my SQL Server Instance and ran the following script:

```
USE Master;
GO

ALTER ENDPOINT [TSQL Default TCP]
STATE=STOPPED;
```

After that I am unable to login.  I can't even login using Windows authentication.

How can I revert the change above?  Is there any another way to fix this situation?

Comment: Can you try restarting the SQL server services? It might help.

Comment: Yes, I have tried this..but still the problem exist..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`STATE = STOPPED` on the `[TSQL Default TCP]` endpoint prevents the SQL Server service from listening for incoming connections via TCP.  You have several options available that will allow you to reverse this.

1. Connect with the DAC dedicated admin connection.  You can connect to the DAC by specifying the name of the server as: `ADMIN:MyServerName`.  Once connected to the DAC, you should be able to start the endpoint again with the following statement:

   ```
   ALTER ENDPOINT[TSQL Default TCP] state = started;
   ```
2. Use named pipes to connect to SQL server. Use SQL Server
   Configuration Manager to enable named pipes if disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Can you edit your post to include the exact error message you are getting?

It sounds like your `sa` account is completely locked out.  If that is the case you may need to install a new instance of SQL Server 2005 and connect all of your databases back to it.

Comment: I tried but problem still exist. In error log Message: "
Error: 17813, Severity: 20, State: 1.
The requested service has been stopped or disabled and is unavailable at this time.
The connection has been closed. [CLIENT: xxx.xxx.9.xxx]
"  and during connection from sqlcmd: "Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Native Client : Login timeout expired.
". While connecting from Managment studio "Microsoft Error 64 reported"